# how can i bind the spacebar to a .onkeypress(function, space bar)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need to add the space bar into a event. I know how to set these things up, but I don't know how to tell python that the space bar is what I want pressed. I have tried...

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(p_jump, " ")
```

but that allows any key that isn't already binded to be pressed.

Comment: Here's a link that should help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(p_jump, "space")
```

According to [How to start moving a turtle via space bar with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904032/how-to-start-moving-a-turtle-via-space-bar-with-python)

Comment: This has worked thank you. Looking at the answer made me feel like an idiot lol!

Comment: You're welcome! Would be helpful to others looking for the same thing if you mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: i was trying to but it said i had to wait 10 mins before i could, i have accepted it now