# Turtle not moving, screen events

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Heello! My turtle is not moving and I don't really know why... May anyone help?

```
import turtle

chocolate = turtle.Turtle()


def move_forward():
    chocolate.forward(10)


screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(fun=move_forward, key="space")

screen.mainloop()
```

I expect my turtle moving with 10 pace when I press "space".

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's working. Tested [here](https://trinket.io/turtle).

```
import turtle

chocolate = turtle.Turtle()
chocolate.shape("turtle")
chocolate.speed(500)

def move_forward():
    chocolate.forward(1)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.onkey(move_forward, "space")
screen.listen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904032/how-to-start-moving-a-turtle-via-space-bar-with-python) can give you more insights. Also `exitonclick()` must be at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

exit on click must be at the end.

```
import turtle

chocolate = turtle.Turtle()


def move_forward():
    chocolate.forward(10)


screen = turtle.Screen()


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(fun=move_forward, key="space")

screen.exitonclick()
```